# How to properly configure credentials for gRPC for C ++?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-translation-api

Good day.

I am writing a small C ++ project and am using Google Cloud Translation API in it. I did not find any examples of Google Cloud Translation API for C ++ that are suitable for me. Therefore, I slightly reworked the Google Cloud Speech API examples. I almost succeeded, but I cannot go through the gRPC authorization.

I have a Google account set up. The `application_default_credentials.json` file is located in the default folder (`~/.config/gcloud`). The `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` command outputs a valid access token.

gRPC connections from the Google Cloud Speech API examples are normally authorized and connected to the Google cloud. But for some reason, gRPC authorization does not occur in my code, which was redesigned for Google Cloud Translation API.

Here is my code:

```
#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>
#include <google/cloud/translate/v3/translation_service.grpc.pb.h>

using google::cloud::translation::v3::TranslationService;
using google::cloud::translation::v3::TranslateTextRequest;
using google::cloud::translation::v3::TranslateTextResponse;
using namespace std;

void Test()
{
  auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
  auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("translation.googleapis.com", creds);
  std::unique_ptr<TranslationService::Stub> translator(TranslationService::NewStub(channel));

  grpc::ClientContext context;

  TranslateTextRequest request;
  request.set_parent("projects/<**My-Project-Id**>/locations/global");
  request.set_source_language_code("en-US");
  request.set_target_language_code("ru");
  request.set_mime_type("text/plain");
  request.add_contents("Hello World!");

  TranslateTextResponse response;
  grpc::Status status = translator->TranslateText(&context, request, &response);

  cout << status.ok() << endl << status.error_message() << endl;
}
```

Running this code displays the following:

```
0 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

Apparently my Credentials settings didn't apply when opening a gRPC connection for some reason.

Can anyone please help me? Has anyone had any experience using the Google Cloud Translation API with gRPC for the C ++ programming language?

Comment: Sometimes this error occurs due to an incorrectly system time.

Comment: According to the [GCP C++ Speech Samples repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-samples/tree/main/speech/api). You may also need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point to your downloaded service account JSON keyfile. Give that a try and let us know the outcome.

Comment: If it still doesn’t work, then please share the exact Speech example that you based your code on, I wasn’t able to find any “google/cloud/translate/v3/translation_service.grpc.pb.h” library anywhere, so it would be useful to see how does the original Speech code looks like and what specific modifications did you make to use it with Cloud Translation.